# How to use HTML Form Element in JBPM 7.13?

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to use the HTML component for showing a PDF file using IFRAME tag ,but the HTML editor is not working as expected.I am getting full HTML code being printed on the screen.

I tried to know how this HTML component works, how can we add our custom HTML code, i am not getting any clue.
The JBPM version i am using is 7.13.with all default settings in place.

I trying to use below HTML code,
[iframe src="http://****:****/****.pdf" style="width: 50%;height: 100%;border: solid;"][/iframe]

I was hoping to see the PDF file being shown in the IFRAME.but it is showing full html code only.

Below are the screen pint of the steps i took:

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYTQn.jpg)
[Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD91C.jpg)
[Part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8vCk.jpg)

Comment: Can you share few more details like how and where are you adding the IFRAME code (steps followed), if possible please share a screenshot also.

Comment: I am working on editing the human  task form generated by the work bench and under this I am using provided HTML form control. While editing the HTML form component I am adding the IFRAME code , and then I am just deploying and running the task.

Comment: Thanks for the details. You can follow steps described below. It's working fine for me on JBPM 7.13. test and share the results.

Comment: Will try the below given step and let you know

Comment: First of all thanks for taking you time out for trying to help me out.I tried the steps given below but no luck it is still not working, i think the html code view works only for some of the predefined html tags for example : bold,underline,h1,h2,h3,img,code,paragraph etc. (the tags which are shown at the top in the heml line). These tags are working fine for me as well.Please try the Iframe tag and see if it is working  for you.please share the screen print if possible on what are you seeing.

Comment: Did you switch view before adding the iframe tag. In default view you can only use predefined tags but once you switched view you can add iframe tag. I tried testing using iframe tag and its working fine for me. If you use any predefined tags like bold to write something and click on switch view, you can see source code auto generated for the same.

Comment: Yes i am switching the view and then i am adding the iframe tag still i am seeing only "Add your HTML here...".Does it need some setting/configuration to be done in order to achieve what you are seeing. I am using binaries provided with packeage "jbpm-installer-full-7.13.0.Final" and with H2 db and all default settings

Comment: I didn't make any change with configuration. Directly downloaded and ran "jbpm-server-7.13.0.Final-dist" . Are you able to see source code auto generated for any text added when you click switch view? Will you be able share screenshot of your screen.

Comment: I am seeing the source code for auto generated tags, I am having a document explaining the steps an dhow it is coming up for me, can you let me know how can i pass it you .

Comment: I have added the screen pint of the document with my question now part1, part2 and part3, kindly have a look.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshots. It looks like it's not picking the code that you have added. Could you just remove the HTML component and insert a new HTML component and try. I faced the same issue in between when tried editing the component many times.

Comment: Even adding new HTML component is Not working for me , it is behaving in the same manner it is not picking that code what i have written.Is there any thing else i should i try.

Comment: This behavior looks strange. If you are in development env, then may be you can try testing with later versions or try different browsers etc.

Comment: i tried this in two other version as well 7.7 and 7.15 with all the browsers i have (Firefox, IE and chrome) but no luck.

Comment: it is working now , i am not sure how but it has started working as expected, thanks for helping me out here

Comment: @SudhishNair, i have one question , i have posted on the below URL, can you please take a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236321/how-to-access-a-form-variable-in-html-component-in-jbpm

Comment: Nice to know that it's working fine now. If you feel answer shared is helpful, you can upvote / mark it has correct. It would help others who may face similar issue. Will check on the other question posted.

Comment: @SudhishNair, I am using KIE workbench 7.28. I cannot find a select box or combo box in the form modeler. any idea?

Comment: @AneerAnwar Are you talking about multiple choice check box?

Comment: @SudhishNair I think I found it . its Listbox. but I have 2 questions: 1) can we load the Listbox using external data source 2) if we have a Listbox depending on other listbox's value, eg: if one list box shows state and other cities of the state, then cities Listbox should listen to the state Listbox change event. is it possible using jbpm form modeler?

Comment: @AneerDev Currently it doesn't seem to be supported, if you want you can go ahead and file a bug in community for it check on it's feasibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to use HTML code.

1) Select HTML component from the Form Controls.

2) Click on Switch View button at top right hand corner to switch to source code view.

[image]

3) Add iframe tag that you want to embed.

[image]

4) You can switch view again to preview the component and save the form.

[image]

I have tested it on JBPM 7.13 and it's working fine.