# How to access a form variable in HTML component in JBPM7.13

Tags: jbpm

I have created a human task form which has only one variable as a input, I want to access that variable in the HTML component I am adding to display the value.

I am not finding any way to achieve this, please help.

I want to display the value of the variable in the HTML component.

[image: Part1]
[image: Part2]

Comment: How are passing the value of input variable? Is value available to form where you are using the HTML component?

Comment: The value are getting from process variable to user task input.yes the value is available in the form.

Comment: If you remember the other question on IFRAME tag where we are passing the hard-coded SRC value , I want to populate the SRC from a variable so that it can display different document as per variable valve.

Comment: It's interesting query, all other form field as option of binding field, but I also didn't find anything for HTML component. You can try to check on JBPM community. I will also check on it.

Comment: i have already raised there as well.Waiting for the response.

Comment: I had a discussion on the same in the community group, they are suggesting it's not possible. You may try to use a custom form renderer.  Refer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jbpm-usage/nN8m6eCVCkY for discussion details.